# is.(':visible') == true on not-visible parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <div class="checkMe"></div>
</div>
```

when I now check `.checkMe` if it is visible..

```
if($('.checkMe').is(':visible')) { ...
```

it is true although it is not

is there a way to achieve the check, without checking the parent-div?

Comment: As you can see from the answer below, what you have should (and does) work absolutely fine. Are you sure you only have one `.checkMe` element in the DOM?

Comment: Returns `false` Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uo463ave/)

Comment: `console.log($('.checkMe').is(':visible'));` prints `false`, as I would expect. What is the body of your `if` block (and the rest of your code) and what are you seeing that indicates it is evaluating to `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is returning the correct value.

```js
if ($('.checkMe').is(':visible')) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="display:none;">
  <div class="checkMe"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: dude.. you're right!! .. it's my own fault. the error is somewhere else! -.- ..soooorrry :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this answer

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <div class="checkMe">child div</div>
</div>
<div id="samp"></div>


var element = jQuery('.checkMe').clone();
element.appendTo('#samp');
if($('.checkMe').is(':visible'))
{
    alert('visible');
}
else
{
    alert('not visible');

}
```